# Django Many Users to One model. A Model about the User

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to figure out how many users can be associated with one instance of a model.

I have a sports club project. There are many users (admin and staff) only one Club. I can't seem to form a many to one relationship with the User model.
I want to filter mainly by the club. 
Say if 3 clubs use the project, each club would want to be separated by the club and not by the user.

Below is a simplified version of my models. 
I've also tried to add the ForeignKey to the club and go the other way.

```
Class Club(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)


Class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What's your question? As an aside, I don't think you want to allows `Club`s and `User`s without names.

Comment: I'm trying to have each User have a many to one relationship with a club. Let's say 3 local clubs use the software. I would like the club as the main model and the people who work for that club be associated to only their club. Similar to how each team would be associated to only one club.

Comment: And your question is what? I'm not trying to be a jerk, but it's not easy to provide an answer unless you provide a question.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is just one club but various users, I believe your model should remain like this but on the user model you can assign different roles for different users in a club

```
Class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your models appropriately. When you create the ForeignKey, each instance of the model that is being associated with (here your Club model) has access to the instances associating with it through a Manager object. You can define the "related_name" argument in the ForeignKey field definition so that your club objects have access to the users associated with them through a custom-defined name (rather than the default name):

```
Class Club(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

Class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name="members", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can then access the related users with club.members.all assuming that "club" is the name of the club context object passed to the Template and "members" is the related_name of the User model's ForeignKey relation to Club. As a trivial example, if you wanted to list the members of a club, you could then do the following:

```
{% for member in club.members.all %}
    <p>{{member.name}} is a member</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Check out this link for more on ForeignKey relations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward